# Display/get details based on ID after clicking button in the table cell in the data table - React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am very new to react. Maybe this is a very simple question. I have a data table with mock data using react data table. How to make table cell clickable and get the data after clicking to display the details on that form? Both form and data table are in the same page.

Here is the link https://codesandbox.io/s/react-table-onclick-row-to-display-data-on-form-unsolved-3636s?

Comment: Create a component that renders both the `Table` and `UserDetails`. Have this component provide the data to display in the table to the `Table` component as well as an `onCellClick` callback that you call with the row id in the `Table` component, when the name is clicked. Store the currently clicked row id in a state in your new component using `useState`. Select the data set using the row id and pass it as a prop to the `UserDetails`. Fill the inputs with the data provided using `useEffect` whenever the details change.

Comment: Thanks for the info! Now I understand a bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified the sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-table-onclick-row-to-display-data-on-form-unsolved-forked-08cp1?file=/src/userdetails.js) stating how to do this, basically you need a state to store the `activeRow`;

Comment: Thank you, now I understand how to do it!

Comment: @WMax welcome, also you can mark the answer as accepted if it solves the problem. Thanks

Comment: Can I ask in details, what is the purpose of activeRow for that

Comment: @WMax the ``activeRow`` is a property we send from ``App`` to persist the currently selected row. You can change the name to ``currentClickedRow`` for more semantic meaning, if we were to persist the ``Id``, that means we have to always search the entire list for that specific row using the ``id``